# How to get innertext between same two tags

Tags: .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack and I want to get the inner text between same two specific tags, for example:

```
<div class="clearfix polyxgo_rm">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-right porm" id="porm_34481"> Detail <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></div>
<div class="holder polyxgo_details" id="details_34481">
    <div class="holder col-lg-12 clearfix">
        <div class="">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" style="width:100%">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 polyxgo_details_minimize text-center"> <span class="polyxgo_bold">max:</span> 50K</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="width:100%;">
                        <div><span class="polyxgo_bold">Exp:</span> 14/12/2018</div>
                        <div><span class="polyxgo_bold">Voucher:</span> 50K</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried but only get first span: 50K

```
var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(html);
        var data= document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='polyxgo_bold']/following-sibling::text()[1]");
        Console.WriteLine(data.InnerText.Trim());
```

I want to get the innertext at line Exp: 14/12/2018

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code samples.

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should notice that [`SelectSingleNode`](https://html-agility-pack.net/select-single-node) will only return a single node. Exactly as the function name says. From the documentation it returns:

> The first HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode that matches the XPath query or a null reference if no matching node was found.

You can use [`SelectNodes`](https://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes) instead. Which returns:

> An HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection containing a collection of nodes matching the HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.XPath query, or null if no node matched the XPath expression.

In your case, this will return 3 values. If this number is always the same, you can simply use this:

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='polyxgo_bold']/following-sibling::text()[1]");
Console.WriteLine(nodes[1].InnerText);
```

Which will output: `14/12/2018`.

---

## Update:

There's another way to do this. You can use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) to check if the inner text is a date, then output it. Like this:

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='polyxgo_bold']/following-sibling::text()[1]");
DateTime dt;
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParse(node.InnerText.Trim(),out dt))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
    }
}
```

---

And another way would be checking if the first text in that span is "Exp:", this way:

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='polyxgo_bold']/following-sibling::text()[1]");
HtmlNodeCollection nodesText = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='polyxgo_bold'][1]");
HtmlNode htmlNode = nodesText.SingleOrDefault(x => x.InnerText.Trim() == "Exp:");
if (htmlNode != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nodes[nodesText.GetNodeIndex(htmlNode)].InnerText.Trim());
}
```

Comment: how about if it not always same. It does not have first span: <span class="polyxgo_bold">max

Comment: @thanh Does it always have the "Exp:" before it?